# Spring scheduled task after server reboot

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I'm working with **@Scheduled** annotation in **Spring 3**. I need to run some tasks every week or every two weeks, so i'm using **cron** expression as parameter e.g.

```
@Scheduled("0 0 2 */7 * *")
```

My question is if i will create scheduled task that must run every 7 days and on the 6-th day i will restart server (with war redeploy) will it reset this scheduled task (and i need to wait 7 days again) or it saves its state and will trigger this task on 7-th anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain it won't survive a JVM restart.

If you want the job to run every seven days you're probably better scheduling it from cron ( or similar external scheduling mechanism ) rather than getting Spring to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `*/7` means but I'm sure that `1/7` in the following cron means:

*Fires at 2am every 7 days every month starting on the first day of the month*

```
@Scheduled("0 0 2 1/7 * ?")
```

Comment: */X means "every X", so */7 must be every 7 days